# Best way to handle many levels data structure

Tags: database, django, tastypie

I'm struggling with a database problem :

In my project, I receive a huge csv file containing 1 row per product, each product having 5 successive categories.

```
Cat_1 A > Cat_2 A > Cat_3 A > Cat_4 A > Cat_5 A > Product 0001
```

I have to import this data, store it and then make it accessible via a Tastypie-powered API.

The issue is : a Cat_3 linked to a Cat_2 may very well NOT be in the same Cat_2 depending on the Cat_1.

Eg.

```
Cat_1 A > Cat_2 A > Cat_3 A

Cat_1 B > Cat_2 A > Cat_3 A  <<<< This Cat_3 should or should not be here.
```

Thus, linking as FK each Cat to its children seems off the table.

**Question :** 
How do I deal with such an import / structure ? How does this translate in Django ORM terms (and ultimately in Tasypie ModelResource) ?

**Thoughts :**

- Linking each Cat to every previous level via one FK per level. Wouldn't it be very bad in terms of perfs ?
- Creating unique Cats (get_or_create Cat_1 A, then get_or_create Cat_2 A with Cat_1 A__id as FK, and so on...). This seems "bad" since one Cat A would (possibly) lead to multiple objects creation..
- Not linking Cats between them but instead having a separate table with "path" objects. A product would be linked to a path object instead of having 5 FKs to Cats <<< Where I'm currently at.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it correctly:
Am instance Cat_2 A belonging to Cat_1 A is not the same as a Cat_2 A belonging to a Cat_1 B object, correct? So those to Cat_2's just happen to share the same name, but can be differentiated by their parent Cat_1?

Comment: Yes, they share the same name but they happen to share the same ID also in the file I'm receiving, which has led me to think there is a "better" way to do this than to create a many, many Cats (many of them sharing the same name.) Plus, in case I'd have to use these as criterias for a search engine on products, it would be rather "bad" imho..

Comment: To me that sounds like they are the same categories when you look at them isolated, since they share even the same id. 
The only thing that is different is their hierarchy. Correct or not?

Comment: Correct :-) Having multiple hierarchies for a same category is where I struggle.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it was wrong. I forgot that parents in your tree affect their grandchildren and not just their children.